# How to zoom webpage body using jquery in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have webpage and i want to zoom its body whenever it load using jquery but css zoom feature not working for mozilla firefox. Currently Using

```
$("body").css("zoom", "1.05");
```

It worked in chrome , opera ,edge but not working in firefox

Since zoom css doesn't working in mozilla, i try this

```
$("body").css("MozTransform","scale("+1.05+")");
```

But it didn't work . It will be great help if you give me solution .

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer for all modern browsers

```
$('body').css({
  'transform'                : 'scale(1.05)',
  'transform-origin'         : '0 0',
  '-moz-transform-origin'    : '0 0',         /*Firefox*/
  '-ms-transform-origin'     : '0 0',         /*IE*/
  '-webkit-transform-origin' : '0 0',         /*Opera/Safari*/
  '-moz-transform'           : 'scale(1.05)', /*Firefox*/
  '-ms-transform'            : 'scale(1.05)', /*IE*/
  '-webkit-transform'        : 'scale(1.05)'  /*Opera/Safari*/
});
```

> **Note :** You can also define CSS `zoom` property like as above code.

Comment: its zooming but it is not using full width leaving some white space in right side how to fix it .

Comment: `Inspect` the white spaces and apply `CSS` for that. Or you can share all of your code here http://pastebin.com/ . And give me the link. @Aniket

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function zoomin() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "50%" 
        }
</script>

<body onload="zoomin()">
<h1>Whatever</h1>
</body>
```